# LoadBalancingChannel exception on DocumentClient.Dispose()

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have hit an issue where after using CosmosDb, an exception occurs if we try to dispose of the DocumentClient shortly after. Waiting a few seconds before disposing causes no exceptions. We have confirmed that we are using await with every asynchronous call.

Psuedo-code:

```
using(DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(...params)) {
    IOrderedQueryable<T> query = this.documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(...params);

    IList<T> documents;
    using (IDocumentQuery<T> documentQuery = query.AsDocumentQuery()) {
        documents = (await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>()).ToList();
    }
    // Processing...
}
```

The exception states:

```
LoadBalancingChannel rntbd://[ip].documents.azure.com:[port]/ in use
```

The API that makes the call successfully returns before DocumentClient.Dispose is called (all of the documents are correctly returned).
Has anyone seen this exception before? A search revealed no hits.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the DocumentClient is disposed while pending requests. this was addressed in SDK version 2.2.2, please upgrade to latest SDK version.